# Image settings work differently on separate pages by Jekyll

Tags: css, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I'm trying to create a personal blog on Github pages using Jekyll. I added a bunch of images, but when adjusting their sizes in css, I have below problem:

On homepage and about pages, CSS works fine, images are shown with correct sizes, but on Code and Life pages, CSS doesn't work. I guess it had something to do with relative path but I don't know how to fix it.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
```

Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/yinkouya/yinkouya.github.io), please kindly help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in _config.yml, set baseurl: ""

and link style sheet like below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS file is being loaded with a relative path, so it won't work if the URL path has more than one level, to fix it use an absolute path.

You can use the `absolute_url` filter that prepends the url and baseurl value to the input.

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
```

to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{'assets/style.css'|absolute_url}}">
```

Comment: By adding the absolute_url filter, somehow the style sheet lose control of all the page settings

Comment: CSS should be loaded in every page no matter where you are calling it.